# Automatically setting table row height

Tags: tables

When creating a table, Latex sometimes doesn't fit the row height well, making the content intersect with the borders as in the following:

[image]

Notice how the first row is too short while the second looks good.

This is generated by the code:

```
\begin{tabular} {   | c | c | }
    \hline
    $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$   & $(1,1)$   \\ \hline      
    $(1,1)$      &  $\left(\frac{1}{1+c},\frac{1}{1+c}\right)$    \\  \hline        
\end{tabular}
```

> Any ideas as to how to make Latex allocate enough space for the rows without explicit commands?

Perhaps the problem is not with the table but rather the parenthesis, so a solution to that (make the parenthesis around the contents of the first cell larger) would help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three main solutions:

1. Use the `cellspace` package, which defines a `minimal` vertical spacing between the contents of a cell and the above or below cell (`\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`). You have to prefix the column specifier with the letter `S`, or `C` if you use `siunitx`.
2. Use the `makecell` package and the pair of commands `\setcellgapes{some length}` (in preamble) and `\setcellgapes` (for specific tables)
3. Use the `booktabs` package and its `toprule`,`\(c)midrule` and `\bottomrule` commands, which add some vertical (adjustable) spacing around them. No vertical rules in this case.

Here is a demo with your specific code. See the details in the documentation of the packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} { | c | c | }
  \hline
  $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ & $(1,1)$ \\ \hline
  $(1,1)$ & $\left(\frac{1}{1+c},\frac{1}{1+c}\right)$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular} { | Sc | Sc | }
  \hline
  $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ & $(1,1)$ \\
  \hline
  $(1,1)$ & $\left(\frac{1}{1+c},\frac{1}{1+c}\right)$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\qquad
{\makegapedcells\begin{tabular} { | c | c | }
  \hline
  $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ & $(1,1)$ \\ \hline
  $(1,1)$ & $\left(\frac{1}{1+c},\frac{1}{1+c}\right)$ \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}}
\vskip1cm
\begin{tabular} {cc}
  \toprule
  $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ & $(1,1)$ \\
  \midrule
  $(1,1)$ & $\left(\frac{1}{1+c},\frac{1}{1+c}\right)$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cute trick.  I like the results better than \arraystretch.

[image: fbox table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\fboxrule=0pt
\begin{tabular} {   | c | c | }
    \hline
    \fbox{$\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$}   & $(1,1)$   \\ \hline      
    $(1,1)$      &  \fbox{$\left(\frac{1}{1+c},\frac{1}{1+c}\right)$}    \\  \hline        
\end{tabular}
\medskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could consider reducing `\tabcolsep` to eat up the `\fboxsep`.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes - Or add a couple of \hspace{-\fboxsep}, if it is a problem.